# Electric current shock in Bathroom water tap

Tags: electrical, plumbing, grounding, troubleshooting

I live in india,

- 1 storeyed apartment with 2 flats on the ground floor and 2 flats on the first floor. It is annexed on the back side with same 2 + 2 model.
- My Bathroom has a 2000 Watts - 15 Liter water heater.
- All the walls are concrete with concealed metal pipes (Mostly Iron)
- We recently switched pipe for the water alone to plastic as the flow was not good
- Recently we switched on the motor pump motor that fills up sump water to one of the tank
- It seems that the motor is broken and also inefficient in its job, still runs and it is also grounded properly (i could get a pic if required)
- However immediately after the motor started i felt shock in my bathroom water tap's running water and very mildly on the tap itself. Although its a metal tap
- This have been a problem for a very long time even without the motor being switched on

this time with the motor switched on and with the help of electrician we tested all the houses and could not find the root cause of the problem. I have a multi meter and not sure where to start or find the root cause of this problem.

Please advise thank you.

Comment: I bet it used to ground via the water pipe that used to be metal.  For years, that has been masking a different problem.  You've had that other problem all along, but now it is revealed and you must find and fix it.

Comment: Are you saying my concealed metal water pipe is used for grounding as well ? Oh boy is that even normal ? and is there any easy fix ? I dont want to bring down the walls to fix this. Also, why is only me facing this problem ? everyone else should also face it right ? When we tested with motor on, i could not replicate this in other flat's bathroom which is adjacent or straight below

Comment: I am saying that you have Problem X (not yet identified) which was electrifying your water *and you have had Problem X for quite a long time*.   As long as the water pipes were iron in concrete, this was protecting you from Problem X.  When you went to plastic pipe, you were no longer protected, and Problem X started affecting you.  **I recommend you identify and fix Problem X** so it doesn't matter if your pipes are metal or not.

Comment: If this occurs with the motor on or off then let's leave it off for a moment (fully disconnect it from power if possible) and look for other sources of electricity. Can you check for shock with the water heater turned on, turned off, and fully disconnected?

Comment: Thanks Harper for the details, the problem x is not because of the changing to the plastic pipe for hot water. Because I was getting shock in th hot water tap when it was using concealed metal pipe and not now. So we could rule out the plastic pipe based hot water tap.

Comment: Greg, I did do switch off the motor and try and I could not replicate. We are lucky this time ,to find out that the shock occurs when the motor runs. Which is not the case always before